# Template deduction failure

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, variadic-templates, sfinae

I'm trying to implement bind function from boost library.
Below you can see the main struct `bind_t` with defined `operator()`.

My question is as follows: Why should we specify in decltype in returning type of `operator()` returning type of `call()` explicitly as member function (if I remove `this->` before `call`, the template argument deduction fails in g++.)

Also interesting, that using clang++ there's no such problem.

I have no idea, why this happens.

```c
template <typename F, typename  ... P>
struct bind_t {
private:
    std::tuple<typename holder<P>::type...> p;
    F func;
    template <size_t ... N, typename ... Args>
    auto call(index_list<N ...>, Args const& ... args) const -> decltype(func(std::get<N>(p)(args...)...)) {
        return func(std::get<N>(p)(args...)...);
    }
public:
    bind_t(F f, P ... p):
        p(std::move(p)...),
        func(std::move(f))
    {}
    template <typename ... Args>
    auto operator()(Args const& ... args) const -> decltype(this->call(typename indices_by_num<sizeof...(P)>::type(), args...)) {
        typename indices_by_num<sizeof...(P)>::type indices;
        return call(indices, args...);
    }
};
```

[full source](https://github.com/artemZholus/cpp-course/blob/master/term3/practice/bind/bind.h) of implementation
[simple usecase](https://github.com/artemZholus/cpp-course/blob/master/term3/practice/bind/main.cpp)

Comment: Looks like it is fixed in gcc 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gcc bug and is documented in the bug report [decltype needs explicit 'this' pointer in member function declaration of template class with trailing return type](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57543) which says:

> When using trailing return-type for member functions of a template
>   class, the 'this' pointer must be explicitly mentioned. This should
>   not be necessary (The implicit 'this' works with a non-template
>   class).
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> struct DecltypeConstThis {
>
>     T f() const { return T{}; }
>
>     auto g() -> decltype(this->f()) { return this->f(); }
>     auto h() const  ->  decltype(f()) { return f(); } // this should work the same as g() above (with implicit 'this')
>
> };
>
> struct Working {
>     int f() const { return 0; }
>     auto h() const -> decltype(f()) { return 0; }
> };
>
>
> int main() {
>
>     Working w;
>     w.h();
>
>     DecltypeConstThis<int> d;
>     d.g();
>     d.h();
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

The report was marked as fixed and it looks like this works starts working in gcc 5.1 (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Vp0h9GuOZzmeyTbS)*).

Comment: If you don't have the most recent versions of gcc you can verify using [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox) and see which version it starts working in.